# How to put question numbers in margin?

Tags: numbering, margins

I'm trying to put numbering to the solutions of my assignment in the margin of my document like so:

[image]

Ideally I'd like to enter the numbers "1.", "2.", ... etc. manually, i.e. not have them numbered automatically. How do I do this? I'm using a modified article class.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) This site works best if questions are accompanied by the code that's been used to generate the intended result. Please also be more specific about what you're trying to achieve; e.g., *where in the margins* should be numbers be located.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @Mico. In this case my previous attempts had all been so off the mark that I didn't they would even be worth including but I'll remember that for the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to me that you are just using a normal `enumerate` environment to do that.

So, to achieve what you want

1. Load the package `enumitem` and add the optional argument `[leftmargin=\labelsep]` to your `enumerate` environment as in

   ```
   \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=\labelsep]
   ```

   to have your label in the margin.
2. Simply use the optional argument of `\item` to manually specify your number as in

   ```
   \item[3.] Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $x_n>0$
   ```

MWE (don't load the `showframe` package in your document, I've used it just to show the margins)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the margins

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=\labelsep]
  \item[3.] Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $x_n>0$
  \[y_n=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_1}+}\]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Suppose that $x_n$ is a convergent
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

If you instead use `[leftmargin=0pt]` you will obtain

[image]

while, with `[leftmargin=*]` the result is

[image]